# Office 365 Delve

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, delve

Hope you're doing well;

I wanted to know what happens if you switch off the office 365 Delve.

Does it impact SharePoint or Office 365.

Kind regards,
Anees

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by switch to Delve?

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from a Microsoft case with the first paragraph notating the impacted services and applications.

> Delve, Office.com (Discover tab, Edge, Tab pages), Office clients
>   Desktop and Web (Home page), Outlook Mobile, SharePoint Home page,
>   Live People Cards, OneDrive for Business (Shared with Me)
>
> Opting out from Office Graph will disable Delve and will affect the
>   document relevancy on all the other Office 365 applications that are
>   built on top of Office Graph. Opting out means that Office Graph will
>   only consider public signals (mainly "modified" actions) to rank
>   relevant items for the user(s). These signals are publicly available
>   for everyone in SharePoint Online and also through search. An example
>   is the Office.com Discover tab. This tab shows a list of relevant
>   items for the user. This feed will always be available even if the
>   user or tenant have opted-out from Office Graph. What will happen is
>   that the relevancy of these items will be poorer, since the graph is
>   limited on the amount and type of signals that are collected and
>   analyzed.